# Detecting a Buffer Overflow in a non open-source program

Tags: assembly, gdb, buffer-overflow

i am reading a book about bufferoverflow exploiting etc.
But there is one question this book doesnt answers. How can i dectect a bufferoverflow using GDB without seeing the source code of the program? Is it possible to detect a bufferflow looking to the assembly?

Comment: If this isn't *your* program (or a program of one of your authorized clients), any attempt at overrunning buffers would be malicious.

Comment: Well, you need to find clues. Reverse engineering is a lot of inference about what is happening (and yes, you can read assembly and understand what is going on just like in C code - you need to simply be familiar with assembly). Often times, programs use standard methods (and sometimes `gdb` or `objdump` will display these names) and you can try to exploit the buffer overflow.

Comment: Do you want to detect if overflow has actually happened, or you are trying to check, if this is possible for this particular code piece? If first, you can set breakpoint 'on memory access' and wait until it happened.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if everybody thought that way, there'd be no vulnerability research at all.

Answer (score 1):

A buffer overflow can result in immediately observable change in behavior (the program crashes or hangs right there) or it can be distant (it crashes or hangs later or it corrupts important data and starts misbehaving and it takes time and attention to see it) or it can be benign (because the overwritten memory isn't used after that point).

Unless you know what you're looking for and are familiar with the code or its disassembly, there's no simple, bulletproof or automatic way of overflow detection in general.

If it's your code, you can find your buffer overflows in a combination of ways:

- code review
- code instrumentation (manual or with some tools) to check sizes, indices and pointers
- testing (including step by step execution in the debugger)

If the code isn't yours and you don't know it and have only the disassembly, things become significantly more complex. You can still try to test it by feeding it specially (maliciously) crafted data. If you get a crash, it may be because of a buffer overflow or it can be close to a place where one can occur.

There exist tools that let you inject faults into a program at the points where it calls OS functions. You could use those to uncover some places with insufficient error checking, possibly with buffer overflows.

It's not a simple problem and there's no simple solution, which may be why the book didn't explicitly address it at the level you wanted. Or you may have missed it.